# How grouping data with php and display it inside table (table in table)?

Tags: php

I have problem when grouping data table in table.
I've made ​​but I think the results are not in accordance with the expected.

**This is the example script :**

```
<?php

$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','root',''); 
mysql_select_db('things',$conn) or die ("Database Not Found"); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, size, color FROM things ORDER BY color");  
$state = -1;
$no = 1;    

echo '<table border=1><tr><td>INDEX OF COLOR</td></tr><tr><td>';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

        if($state!= $row['color']) {
            $no = 1;
            echo '<tr bgcolor=yellow><td>'.$row['color']."</td></tr>";
            echo '<tr><td><table border=1><tr><th>no</th><th>NAME OF HERO</th></tr>';
            $state = $row['color'];
        }

        echo '<tr><td>'.$no.'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';




        $no++;

    } 

    echo '</td></tr></table>';  

?>
```

That code produces the wrong table in the table. The desired outcome is the Color Group>> Details (Table).

I need result like this :)

```
+-------------------+
| INDEX OF COLOR    |
+-------------------+
|RED                |
+-------------------+
| +----------+      |
| |HERO      |      |
| +----------+      |
| |ROBIN     |      |
| +----------+      |
| |INCREDIBLE|      |
| +----------+      | 
+-------------------+
|BLUE               |
+-------------------+
| +----------+      |
| |HERO      |      |
| +----------+      |
| |SPIDEY    |      |
| +----------+      |
| |SUPER MAN |      |
| +----------+      |   
| |ICE MAN   |      | 
| +----------+      |
+-------------------+
```

can anyone help me, why this code wrong?
Thank you. :)

Comment: What result are you getting now?

Comment: Current result : http://bahalabs.com/uploads/error.png

Comment: Your title doesn't need to be ALL CAPS. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Oh sorry, OK thanks :) it is my first posting. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your table is way more complex than it needs to be. I haven't tested this, but try it out.

```
$first_color = true;
echo '<table border=1><tr><td>INDEX OF COLOR</td></tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    if($state!= $row['color']) {
        if(!$first_color) {
            echo '</table></td></tr>';
            $first_color = true;
        }
        $no = 1;
        echo '<tr bgcolor=yellow><td>'.$row['color']."</td></tr>";
        echo '<tr><td><table border=1><tr><td>no</td><td>NAME OF HERO</td></tr>';
        $state = $row['color'];
    }

    echo '<tr><td>'.$no.'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td></tr>';




    $no++;

} 

echo '</table></td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: :D sorry $sasas just for debug. hahaha forgot to remove it.

Comment: Thanks before, but i need the details is table format in the table parent (color) like this http://bahalabs.com/uploads/right.png

Comment: This is a somewhat complex layout you have here! try my edited solution. notice I added a `$first_color = true;` line at the top.